# Grid and Frames in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, grid, frame

Can we place grid of buttons inside a Frame or can we use both frame and pack inside one class?

I wanted to make a simple GUI based calculator in python like this.

[image: required output]

P.S I'm new to python GUI. Assuming my Basics are not clear

This is what i got by using only Grids

[image: Grid output]

**Code**

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title("Calculator")
Entry(root).grid(row=0, column=0)

one = Button(
        root,
        text="1",
        width=5,
        height=1
             ).grid(row=1, column=1)

two = Button(
        root,
        text="2",
        width=5,
        height=1
             ).grid(row=1, column=2)
three = Button(
        root,
        text="3",
        width=5,
        height=1
             ).grid(row=1, column=3)
four = Button(
        root,
        text="4",
        width=5,
        height=1
             ).grid(row=1, column=4)
five = Button(
        root,
        text="5",
        width=5,
        height=1
             ).grid(row=2, column=1)
six = Button(
        root,
        text="6",
        width=5,
        height=1
             ).grid(row=2, column=2)
seven = Button(
        root,
        text="7",
        width=5,
        height=1
             ).grid(row=2, column=3)
eight = Button(
        root,
        text="8",
        width=5,
        height=1
             ).grid(row=2, column=4)
nine = Button(
        root,
        text="9",
        width=5,
        height=1
             ).grid(row=3, column=1)
zero = Button(
        root,
        text="0",
        width=5,
        height=1
             ).grid(row=3, column=2)

sin = Button(
        root,
        text="sin",
        width=5,
        height=1
             ).grid(row=3, column=3)

cos = Button(
        root,
        text="cos",
        width=5,
        height=1
             ).grid(row=3, column=4)

tan = Button(
        root,
        text="Tan",
        width=5,
        height=1
             ).grid(row=4, column=1)

sqrt = Button(
        root,
        text="Sqt",
        width=5,
        height=1
             ).grid(row=4, column=2)
reset = Button(
        root,
        text="C",
        width=5,
        height=1
             ).grid(row=4, column=3)
result = Button(
        root,
        text="=",
        width=5,
        height=1
             ).grid(row=4, column=4)

add = Button(
    root,
    text="+",
    width=5,
    height=1
).grid(row=1, column=0)

subtract = Button(
    root,
    text="-",
    width=5,
    height=1
).grid(row=2, column=0)

Multiply = Button(
    root,
    text="*",
    width=5,
    height=1
).grid(row=3, column=0)

Divide = Button(
    root,
    text="/",
    width=5,
    height=1
).grid(row=4, column=0)
root.mainloop()
```

I also tried to use frame for input field but got this error.

> self.tk.call(
> _tkinter.TclError: cannot use geometry manager grid inside . which already has slaves managed by pack

**Code**

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Calculator")
# input frame
input_frame = Frame(root)
input_frame.pack()
a = Entry(input_frame, width=100)
a.pack()
one = Button(
        root,
        text="1",
        width=5,
        height=1
             ).grid(row=1, column=1)

two = Button(
        root,
        text="2",
        width=5,
        height=1
             ).grid(row=1, column=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Is there any way to use both frames and grids to achieve [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HI9IT.png)?

Comment: Change `Entry(root).grid(row=0, column=0)` to `Entry(root).grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=5, sticky="ew")`.  I would suggest you to split the line into two lines: `display = Entry(root)` and `display.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=5, sticky="ew")` because you need to access the entry box later.

Comment: In first code you can add Frame.. frame=Frame(root,bg="red")
frame.pack()
Entry(frame).grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=5, sticky="ew")

one = Button(
        frame,   Change the root to frame for every biutton widgets.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can add Frame in every widgets.
Change this:

```
Button(
        root,
```

To:

```
Button(
        input_frame,
```

This is what is look like:

[image]